# execvp returns with perimission denied error in c

Tags: c, permissions, fork, exec

I want to write a program that uses exec in order to mutate a child and use it to do a curtain action.
The child has to calculate a simple equation (-,+,*,/).
When I try to access the file using `execvp` I get the following error:

> execvp() failed!: Permission denied

Anyone has an idea what have I done wrong?
Here is my code down below.

```
int main()
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);   //ignore child signal from now on
    pid_t status;
    char *a[2] = { "calculator", "2+1", NULL };

    status = fork();
    if (status != 0)
    {
        do_child(0, a);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
 *  id 0: calculator
 *  id 1: factorial
 *  id 2: pid
 */

 void do_child(int id, const char *args[])
 {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        if (execvp("../ex2cFactorial/ex2cCalculator.c", args) != 0)
        {
            perror("execvp() failed!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        break;
        //other cases (haven't been written yet)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does it compile without warnings?  
`char *a[2] = { "calculator", "2+1", NULL };`  
Putting 3 pointers in an array holding 2 elements is a trick, that compilers don't like.  
Are you sure that your file `ex2cCalculator.c` is an executable?

Comment: `ex2cCalculator.c` sounds like a source code file that most probably doesn't have the exec bit set. You probably mean `ex2cCalculator` or whatever name you use for the compiled and linked executable.

Comment: this statement: `char *a[2] = { "calculator", "2+1", NULL };` is actually three parameters, not 2.  Suggest: `char *a[] = { "calculator", "2+1", NULL };`  so as to let the compiler figure out that array `a[]` needs to be 3 pointers long.

Comment: this line: `if (execvp("../ex2cFactorial/ex2cCalculator.c", args) != 0)` is missing the final NULL parameter.  the line should be: `if (execvp("../ex2cFactorial/ex2cCalculator.c", args, NULL ) != 0)`

Comment: the `switch()` statement probably should have a `default:` case

Comment: the code block beginning with: `if (status != 0)` is not properly handling the case when an error occurs with the call to `fork()` (returned value is -1)

Comment: the parent MUST not exit without first calling `waitpid()` for each child that was started,  Otherwise any still running child becomes a `zombie` process.  Zombie processes are very difficult to get rid of without rebooting the computer.  One consequence of this is that the the parent must keep the PID of the child AND the SIGCHLD signal should not be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`ex2cCalculator.c` is a probably a source file, what you need there is the name of the executable (`ex2cCalculator`, `a.out` whatever)

There are also excess elements in the array initializer. It should be `char *a[3] = { "calculator", "2+1", NULL };`